# XPath: how to select a subset of children of the current node

Tags: xml, xpath

I am practicing with XPath and having a hard time understanding some concepts.

From the snippet below I wish to select the `w1ident` and `w1slavetype` elements of the `w1slave` node whose element `w1slavename` has the value `livingroom`.

```
 <w1slave create="2017-01-05 12:39:41">
   <w1ident>28-0000000FBAA6</w1ident>
   <w1identprefix>28</w1identprefix>
   <w1slavetype>THERM_DS18B20</w1slavetype>
   <w1slavename>familyroom</w1slavename>
 </w1slave>
 <w1slave create="2017-01-05 12:39:45">
   <w1ident>28-000005e2fdc3</w1ident>
   <w1identprefix>28</w1identprefix>
   <w1slavetype>THERM_DS18B20</w1slavetype>
   <w1slavename>livingroom</w1slavename>
 </w1slave>
```

The XPath expression `//w1slave[w1slavename='livingroom']/w1ident` works, as does replacing `w1ident` with `w1slavetype`.

But once I have selected the parent node with `//w1slave[w1slavename='livingroom']`, is there a compact means of requesting specific children without having to repeat the initial selection?

Like

```
//w1slave[w1slavename='livingroom']/w1ident |   

//w1slave[w1slavename='livingroom']/w1slavetype
```

works, but feels cumbersome.

Comment: I'm new enough to stackexchange I don't know how to vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `self::` axis in a predicate:

```
//w1slave[w1slavename='livingroom']/*[self::w1ident or self::w1slavetype]
```

Also, if you're using XPath 2.0 you can ditch the predicate and just use the union (`|`) in parens:

```
//w1slave[w1slavename='livingroom']/(w1ident|w1slavetype)
```

Comment: Thanks.  The 1st of the two options work so my browser must not be XPath 2.0 compliant.

Comment: Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

w1ident:

```
'//w1slavename[text()="familyroom"]/preceding-sibling::w1ident'
```

w1slavetype

```
'//w1slavename[text()="familyroom"]/preceding-sibling::w1slavetype'
```

Comment: I like the format of the selection but is there a means to combine the two preceding-siblings into one query?  For example,  //w1slave[w1slavename='livingroom']/* will return all children of the slave node, but this is more than I want.  I would prefer to not make two separate queries.